# Blazor integration tests

Tags: blazor, integration-testing, blazor-webassembly, grpc-c#

I was reading this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44909) (topic is locked), and if I understood correctly, integration tests are not possible with Blazor? My architecture is as follows:

Blazor WASM ASP.NET Core hosted solution, were server project works as identity server and BFF. It mostly accepts requests through Web API, and then passes the requests to other services through GRPC. Majority of APIs require authenticated user.

Flow: SPA client issues http request to API (ControllerBase), which instantiates xxxService class that wraps a gRPC call to some external service.

So, my question is: is it possible to test web API directly, and if not, to test a xxxService, effectively testing GRPC connection and its response?